# How to automatically assign time value 0 to the last data of a series for many series and make a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

My file is composed of several females on which we followed the maturation of the eggs by ultrasound. We therefore have several dates with the size of the eggs for 36 females.
Basically this is what the table looks like

Date           Female Egg size
05/01/2020 a 0.2
05/01/2020 b 0.25
06/02/2020 a 0.3
06/02/2020 b 0.36
07/15/2020 a 0.52
07/17/2020 b 0.5

I would like to make a graph by assigning the egg-laying date for each female as day 0 and invert the dates according to the days of maturation.
Approximate example: 07/15 = D0, 06/02 = -D43 and 05/01 = -D74 (first picture)

My graph is like the second picture for the moment

Thanks and have a great day

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxq5k.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMil3.png)

Comment: Please provide your data as code

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package `lubridate`: there are functions such as:

```
lubridate::interval(date1, date2)
```

to mesure the number of days between two dates. After that, using `lubridate::round_date(date, unit = "day")` will give you the number of days, with day format, and not weeks for instance, between the two dates.

As you're new on SO (welcome !), please provide a sample fo your data using `dput` so we can write a proper code, and not an explaination as I just did

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying to insert the dataframe but I can't...

So you can use the following link to found my table https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjqplow5atsfpp9/Classeur1.txt?dl=0

There are 4 columns (Laying DATE NUM_ID_FEMELLES EGG_DIAM)

Laying, NO = ultrasound checking, YES = laying at this date
DATE = manipulation femelle date
NUM_ID_FEMELLES = Femelle identity
EGG_DIAM = egg size diameter
Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I am trying to insert the dataframe but I can't...

So you can use the following link to found my table
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjqplow5atsfpp9/Classeur1.txt?dl=0

There are 4 columns (Laying DATE    NUM_ID_FEMELLES EGG_DIAM)

- Laying, NO =  ultrasound checking, YES = laying at this date
- DATE = manipulation femelle date
- NUM_ID_FEMELLES = Femelle identity
- EGG_DIAM = egg size diameter

Thanks a lot for your time